# I want to enable display or hide in my mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

[image: the image is my table]

This is my table. I need user to be able to be enable to either show or hide these attributes in their profile. For eg. a user might want to see city in profile but not the country. How do I do this without changing the structure of this table.

Comment: javascript or clever use of backend script

Comment: It is not something you would do in mysql. mysql just stores the data. You will have to program that in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is more of a front-end problem (rather than back-end)... One way you could perhaps solve this is to retrieve all data you need from the database for the selected user, and show a subset of the user data (that most users will likely want to see - name, age, favourite food etc)

Then you could use something like jQuery to power a 'Show more' toggle which will show/hide and give you the rest of the info.

```
SELECT a.*
     , b.*
  FROM contacts a -- assuming this is what your table is called
  LEFT JOIN attributes b -- guessing that's the name of your example table
    ON ( a.contact_id = b.contact_id )
 WHERE a.contact_id = :contact_id -- bind variable
```

I would refrain from using the asterisk (*) in favour of just selecting the columns you need (you can write appropriate indexes and speed up the SQL this way).

If you've got a ton of data about a user (more than just basic stuff such as their name and some simple attributes) - then you might want to adopt a similar approach to above - but only retrieve the *additional* data you need if a user clicks 'Show more'.